# Special characters §§ converting to ?? in browser

Tags: asp.net

Some special characters §§ is converting to ?? in some browsers query string.. How to avoid this.

When I am trying to send it in a **quertstring** its getting converted to ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`

Here is a MSDN link for the [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example

```
 string destinationURL = "http://www.contoso.com/default.aspx?user=test";
 NextPage.NavigateUrl = "~/Finish?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL);
```